# PHP 5.6: password_verify function not returning correctly

Tags: php, passwords, password-encryption

I'm working on the login for my website. I use the `password_hash()` function when creating the account, and store it in a MSSQL database as an nvarchar with 255 length. When I am trying to check the password given when a user is logging in, it never returns true. I've looked at some similar questions, but can't find anything that answers my problem.

**Password encryption:**

```
$user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];

// crypt the user's password with PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character
// hash string. the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5
$user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

...

```
// write new user's data into database
$sql = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email)
        VALUES(:username, :password, :email)");
//sanitizing data to make sure no SQL or HTML gets injected
$sql -> bindParam(':username', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql -> bindParam(':password', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql -> bindParam(':email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert = $sql->execute();
```

**Password decryption:**

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE user_email = :email OR user_name = :username;";
$sql = $this->db_connection->prepare($query);
$sql -> bindParam(':username', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql -> bindParam(':email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql -> execute();

$result_of_login_check = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);           

// if this user exists
if ($result_of_login_check->user_id != null) {
    // get result row (as an object)
    $result_row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
    // the hash of that user's password
    if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row[2])) {

        // write user data into PHP SESSION 
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row[0];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row[1];
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row[3];
        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['success'] = 0;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You are using `->fecth()` **2** times, so the second will try to get the next row in the result set, which probably does not exist. Remove the `$result_row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` and just use the `$result_of_login_check` in your `password_verify()` and setting the Session variables below.

Comment: Also, why are you specifying `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` in `$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`, but accessing it as a numeric array -> `$result_row[0]`/`$result_row[1]`/etc?

Comment: Oh man I totally didn't realize that I had it in twice. That makes so much sense. And I was only using the numeric array index to access it because I had tried to use it as an object and pull the info from it like `$result_row -> user_id` but it hadnt worked, I'm guessing for the same reason. This helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// if this user exists
if ($rst = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) != null) {
    // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
    // the hash of that user's password
    if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $rst->user_password_hash) {

        // write user data into PHP SESSION 
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $rst->user_id;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $rst->user_name;
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $rst->email;
        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['success'] = 0;
    }
}

?>
```

I would however perform more checks before you execute the password_verify() function cause its quite a performance hog. Like Captcha or add max attempts and then call a timeout for a minute.